# how to get normcounts for singlecellexperiment object?

Tags: r, rna-seq, scrnaseq

I need to perform differential expression analysis using the [scDD package](https://rdrr.io/bioc/scDD/f/inst/doc/scDD.pdf) from R, but I am not able to since I miss the **normcounts** assay in my SCE object (of course in the example they show, the assay is already there).

As I found out in the preprocessing steps, one can use [this function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/scDD/man/preprocess.html) to generate the missing assay, except that it does not work:

```
# this is the SCE object
> cTSubSet
class: SingleCellExperiment 
dim: 19767 149 
metadata(2): Samples Samples
assays(2): counts logcounts
rownames(19767): Xkr4 Gm19938 ... CAAA01147332.1 AC149090.1
rowData names(4): ID Symbol Type chrLoc
colnames(149): AAAGGATGTTCACGAT-1 AACCATGTCTTTCGAT-1 ...
  TGTGGCGTCTCTTAAC-1 TTTGGTTAGACGCTCC-1
colData names(17): Sample Barcode ... slm_1 slm_1.5
reducedDimNames(0):
mainExpName: NULL
altExpNames(0):

# setting parameters as suggested in the vignette linked above
> paR <- list(alpha=0.01, mu0=0, s0=0.01, a0=0.01, b0=0.01)
# setting zero.thresh to zero since I already removed unwanted genes
> cTSubSet <- preprocess(cTSubSet, zero.thresh=0, scran_norm=TRUE)

# the not so useful error:
Performing scran Normalization
Error in t.default(Data) : argument is not a matrix
```

I was also looking for other possible ways of obtaining such **normcounts** assay and I found [this description](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/SingleCellExperiment/inst/doc/intro.html):

> normcounts: Normalized values on the same scale as the original
> counts. For example, counts divided by cell-specific size factors that
> are centred at unity.

Still, I can't figure out what this may mean. Is there a way of obtaining such **normcounts**?

Comment: You might as well try [monocle3::normalized_count](https://rdrr.io/github/cole-trapnell-lab/monocle3/man/normalized_counts.html).
It takes SingleCellExperiment object.

Comment: yep that is a possibility. I actually found another one using edgeR, i.e.
`y <- DGEList(counts=(counts(cTSubSet)), group=cTSubSet$condition)`
`y <- calcNormFactors(y)`
however, I am still working on this

Answer (score 2):

I do not know this package but it seems to call `scran` so why bothering and not call `scran` directly, see for an extended discussion + code:

https://bioconductor.org/books/release/OSCA/normalization.html#normalization-by-deconvolution

Comment: yes, I am familiar with the OSCA pipeline. At this point I am just wondering if the values that are returned by `computeSumFactors()` can be considered as **normcounts**.